# Ascii characters in window.open();

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use window.open(); to open a new window and to add parameters to the end of the URL. However when I enter curly braces {} it converts it to the hex code (%7b and %7d).

Does anyone know how to actually make these print out in plain text?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js")}

sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';

function errorMsg() {
    if (**field 1** == "") {
        return "Error please check all fields are completed";
    } else return "";
}

var error = errorMsg();
if (error != ''){
    alert(error);
    console.log('####' + error);
    } else if (error == ''){
    window.open("https://www.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/PointMerge.aspx?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_80}&id={!Opportunity.Id}&ESContactid={QVar0}","","width=700,height=450");
}
```

I have tried converting the curly braces to the, usually accepted, oct codes (\173) but I still get the same %7b output :/

I have also tried splitting the URL and having the {QVar0} in a separate sting and just adding them together:

```
window.open("https://www.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/PointMerge.aspx?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_80}&id={!Opportunity.Id}&ESContactid=" + "{QVar0}");
```

But again same output :/

p.s my actual code and URL are a lot longer... I just got rid of the crap so it was easier to read :)

Thanks for all comments in advance :)

Comment: I don't think those are acceptable in an URL without encoding. Might be worth to add the conga comment you added on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your comments I have fixed this :)

I was silly and made things too complicated.... decodeURIComponent()

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js")}

sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';

function errorMsg() {
    if (**field 1** == "") {
        return "Error please check all fields are completed";
    } else return "";
}

var error = errorMsg();

var URL = decodeURIComponent("https://www.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/PointMerge.aspx?sessionId={!API.Session_ID}&serverUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_80}&id={!Opportunity.Id}&ESContactid={QVar0}");

if (error != ''){
    alert(error);
    console.log('####' + error);
    } else if (error == ''){
    window.open(URL,"","width=700,height=450");
}
```